# Retain history of moved file when importing from SVN to Git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

A question to Git gurus. I am facing the following problem: I need to import a project to Git from SVN with history. The way I do it: git svn clone "http://server/trunk/path/to/my/project". The history is being imported fine...till the point that particular file was moved to its current location from another location. Of course if I use url which is higher, e.g. includes both old and new location, I can track it using history of the old parent folder. The problem is that I can't import the project with old file location as it is not in my ownership. Is there a way to retain the history before the point a file was moved while importing only the project with file's new location?

Comment: Is the history lost even when querying with `git log --follow`?

Comment: It is lost in the described scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For a one time import, you could [give SubGit a try](https://subgit.com/).

As show in [this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Retain-full-history-of-moved-Subversion-directory-in-Git-using/qaq-p/417155):

> SubGit imports/synchronizes only those branches and tags specified on SVN settings page.
>
> So, in order to keep the history for all the previous locations of your `trunk` folder, please include all those locations into `trunk` & `branches` options just as follows:

```
Subversion URL = http://host/svn/repo

Trunk = dir3:refs/heads/master

Branches = dir2:refs/heads/old_master; dir1:refs/heads/even_older_master; branches/*:refs/heads/*

...
```

> With these settings specified SubGit should be able to join the history for all three locations.

That would assume the "other location" is in the same repository though.